# How to convince Agda a function terminates with a reducing number inside a pair?

Tags: agda

I am encoding and proving correctness for the code generation portion of a compiler within Agda. I am having a hard time convincing Agda that some of my functions terminate. The high-level language I am using has while loops, so obviously for any given program there is no guarantee of termination.

Because of this I am using a "fuel" variable, which is just a natural number and decrements by one as each expression is executed, limiting the number of steps a program can run for.

I am satisfied that this guarantees termination, but Agda is not so easily convinced.

```
 data Stateᴴᴸ : Set where
   stateᴴᴸ : Store → (fuel : ℕ) → Stateᴴᴸ

 {-# TERMINATING #-}
 storeᴴᴸ' : IExp → Stateᴴᴸ → Stateᴴᴸ
 storeᴴᴸ' i (stateᴴᴸ σ 0)                           = stateᴴᴸ σ 0
 storeᴴᴸ' SKIP                  (stateᴴᴸ σ (suc f)) = stateᴴᴸ σ f
 storeᴴᴸ' (x ≔ a)               (stateᴴᴸ σ (suc f)) = stateᴴᴸ ((x ≔ aexe a σ) ∷ σ) f
 storeᴴᴸ' (P ⋯ Q)               state = storeᴴᴸ' Q (storeᴴᴸ' P state)
 storeᴴᴸ' (IF b THEN P ELSE Q) (stateᴴᴸ σ (suc f)) with bexe b σ
 ... | true  = storeᴴᴸ' P (stateᴴᴸ σ f)
 ... | false = storeᴴᴸ' Q (stateᴴᴸ σ f)
 storeᴴᴸ' (WHILE b DO c)       (stateᴴᴸ σ (suc f)) with bexe b σ
 ... | true  = storeᴴᴸ' (c ⋯ (WHILE b DO c)) (stateᴴᴸ σ f)
 ... | false = stateᴴᴸ σ f
```

In the code above I have to use the terminating pragma otherwise Agda makes the following complaint:

```
Termination checking failed for the following functions:
  storeᴴᴸ'
Problematic calls:
  storeᴴᴸ' Q (storeᴴᴸ' P state)
  storeᴴᴸ' P state
  storeᴴᴸ' (c ⋯ (WHILE b DO c)) (stateᴴᴸ σ f)
```

I initially thought this was because my `Stateᴴᴸ` datatype did not have the recursive structure that `ℕ` does. So I modified it to the following:

```
  data Stateᴴᴸ : Set where
    stateᴴᴸ : Store  → Stateᴴᴸ
    sucstateᴴᴸ : Stateᴴᴸ → Stateᴴᴸ
```

And changed the function accordingly; but this did not fix the issue.

How can I convince Agda this function (and other similar functions using the same idea) will terminate? (Ideally without modifying the datatypes too much.)

Answer (score 3):

You do structural recursion over two arguments: the structure of your expression and the fuel. Sometimes the fuel goes down and sometimes the expression goes down, but it is not the case that the other one stays the same. This is not in general terminating. You can only do recursion along the lexical product of orders.